# CASE in sql select statement.

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my application I have a very simple sql statement that looks like this:

```
select state from users;
```

And it gaves me the following result:

```
 state 
-------
     5
(1 row)
```

But I want to have some text in result instead of number. For example:

- if state is equal to 5 state should be 'imported'
- if state is equal to 4 state should be 'importing'

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need a simple case clause:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN state = 5 
            THEN 'imported' 
        WHEN state = 4 
            THEN 'importing' 
    END 
FROM users;
```